# Spectral radius and operator norm

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, spectral-radius

Consider a FINITE endomorphism $A$ , then I was wondering whether the relation between the operator norm and the spectral radius $\rho$, given by:
$\|A\| \ge \rho(A)$ is true for all operator norms or only the 2-norm?

Comment: It's true for all operator norms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true, not only for all operator norms, but also for all submultiplicative matrix norms: for any eigenpair $(\lambda,x)$ of $A$, repeat $x$ to form the columns of a square matrix $X$. Then $|\lambda|\|X\|=\|\lambda X\|=\|AX\|\le\|A\|\|X\|$ and hence $|\lambda|\le\|A\|$.